# FlatList single select cell

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I followed the example from official docs, here is how to implement multiselection feature:

```js
state = { selected: (new Map(): Map<string, boolean>) };

onPressItem = (id) => {
  this.setState((state) => {
    const selected = new Map(state.selected);
    selected.set(id, !selected.get(id)); 
    return { selected };
  });
};
```

I'm struggling with making it single select though. It's easy to return new Map with false values anytime cell is tapped, but that means the cell cannot be deselected by another tap on it, which is the desired feature in my case.

```js
onPressItem = (id) => {
  this.setState((state) => {
    const selected = new Map();
    selected.set(id, !selected.get(id)); 
    return { selected };
  });
};
```

How would you implement it? Should I use lodash to iterate over the Map to find the one that already is true and change its value (now sure how to iterate over Map though), or maybe there is some better approach I am missing right now?

**EDIT**

Iterating over elements of the `selected` Map seems to be a really ugly idea, but it is simple and it actually works. Is there any better way to do it that I am missing out on?

```js
onPressItem = (id: string) => {
  this.setState((state) => {
    const selected = new Map(state.selected);
    selected.set(id, !selected.get(id));
    for (const key of selected.keys()) {
      if (key !== id) {
        selected.set(key, false);  
      } 
    }
    return { selected };
  });
 };
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could use filter method from the array object for removing it, but this is to remove not to add. 
To add the spread operator with the new item seems to be the correct way of doing this.
In any case that will be with an if statement to detect if its already on the collection... I can try to think in cleaner ideas :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just set only one value instead of a map like this

```js
onPressItem = (id) => {
  this.setState((state) => {
    const selected = selected === id ? null : id; 
    return { selected };
  });
};
```

Comment: what is selected in your case, is it a new map or Map(state.selected)? what should `selected` piece of state look like?

Comment: My version is based on this example https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html
If I store single id I guess i'd have a problem with rerendering. Thanks in advance

Comment: no a Map is a data structure that contains many elements "mapped" by some keys => key/value data structure, they used it in the example because they needed to store ALL selected elements, in you case you don't need that you only need to store the id of the ONLY selected element.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my solution was:

```
_onPressItem = (id: string) => {
        // updater functions are preferred for transactional updates
        this.setState((state) => {
            // copy the map rather than modifying state.
            const selected = new Map(state.selected);

            // save selected value
            let isSelected = selected.get(id);

            // reset all to false
            selected.forEach((value, key) => {
                selected.set(key, false);
            });

            // then only activate the selected
            selected.set(id, !isSelected);

            return { selected };
        });
    };
```